# Значение выражения "тупой как сибирский валенок"

Tags: фразеология

Является ли оскорблением выражение "тупой как сибирский валенок"?

Answer (score 1):

В коммуникации оценка коннотаций (дополнительных значений) различна для всех участников. Для одного фраза может быть безобидной, тогда как для второго это языковая игра, для третьего - оскорбление.

1. У говорящего было намерение оскорбить собеседника или третье лицо.
2. У говорящего не было такого намерения.
3. Собеседник (или третье лицо) воспринял произнесенную фразу как оскорбление.
4. Собеседник (или третье лицо) не воспринял произнесенную фразу так.

Добавьте сюда ситуацию общения и социальный статус собеседников. Представьте, что фраза "тупой как сибирский валенок" прозвучала в отношении директора из уст подчиненного. Или эта фраза прозвучала из уст политика в теледебатах.

Добавьте сюда интонацию, мимику...

Даже самое, казалось бы, безобидное слово - может быть оскорбительным.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это всего лишь форма, удобство в ущерб красоте. В смысле "свой в доску", "простецкий".

Comment: Тупой как сибирский валенок - это констатация факта, безусловно. Человек тупой, упрямый и безмозглый - конечно, валенок!

Answer (score 0):

В принципе признаки оскорбления можно усмотреть, но недоказательно.
Без контекста такие вещи не определяются.